# Safari transitional background flickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `jquery.scrollie.min.js`, for changing background color while scrolling. You can find an example of what I'm using [HERE](http://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG). I really liked this transition effect when changing the background.

So while I was adding content and some more animation on the page (On my page I also have some [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) on viewport effects), there is some flickering and FOUC whenever scrolling the page.

This can be strange, but I noticed this flickering only in Safari, Chrome for example is doing fine.

```
<!--slide background-->
<div class="slide" data-background="#a4d4ab">
    <div class="inside">
        <p class="wow flipInX" data-wow-delay="1s">I Wanted to create a really simple pen</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END Slide Background-->

<!--slide background-->
<div class="slide" data-background="#e4e6cc">
    <div class="inside">
        <p class="wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="1s">A pen that uses some awesome colors <br /><span>awesome <a href="http://flatuicolors.com/" target="_blank">like these</a></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END Slide Background-->
```

The transitional effect is on the `body` tag:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    transition: background 1s ease;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

JS line that gives `body` dynamic color while scrolling trough sections (`slide`):

```
$('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
```

Did someone had this kind of issue before? Or how this issue can be solved?

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;`? Also, please provide a working example in code, not only pasting it here.

Comment: @Roy, The working example is [here](http://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG). I used the same structure, but added some more animation on my page. In the beginning it worked well, but after adding some more animation, started to flicker.

Comment: @Roy to answer you question, yes I've tried both, but doesn't help at all